# facebook js SDK not working with some users when loading facebook albums

Tags: javascript, facebook, angularjs

I have a problem with several facebook users when I load their albums with java script SDK. I use this permissions 'user_friends, friends_photos' and this code:

```
$scope.getAlbums = function(id) {
FB.api("/"+id+"/albums?limit=1000", function(response) {
    if (response && !response.error) {
        var responseDataLength = response.data.length;
        var albums = [];
        if(response.data.length > 0){
            for (var i = response.data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (typeof response.data[i].cover_photo != "undefined") {
                    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+response.data[i].cover_photo+"/picture?type=thumbnail&access_token="+ $scope.persone_me.facebook_token;
                }
                id = response.data[i].id;
                name = response.data[i].name;
                albums.push({
                    url : url,
                    id : id,
                    name : name
                });
            };
        } else{
            FB.api("/"+id+"/picture?height=600&redirect=false", function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });

        }
        // Apply changes to albums
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.albums = albums;
        });
    }
    });
}
```

Only common thing for this users is a shorter fb id(9 digits)... I do not know if it's coincidence...

Comment: What is the problem? What happens?

Comment: I get the empty array, but I know for sure they have fb albums.

Comment: My guess is that you are using API v2.0 which friends_photos doesn't exists in.

Comment: but for all 99% of others fb friends I get normal response.

Comment: Have you ruled out that the friends' privacy settings are set to disallow apps their friends use from accessing their photos?

Comment: Yes I ruled out that...